# How do i use 2 buttons to do the same thing

Tags: c#

hey im kinda new to coding i was wondering how i would use two buttons to execute the same thing, only the first button works the second doesn't 
code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Send(richTextBox1.Text);
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Send(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

the Send thing:

```
void Send(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            callbytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(cbuf_address);
            if(command == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must enter a command before pressing Send!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                if(cbuf_addtext_alloc == IntPtr.Zero)


                {
                    cbuf_addtext_alloc = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)cbuf_addtext_wrapper.Length, AllocationType.Commit | AllocationType.Reserve, MemoryProtection.ExecuteReadWrite);
                    commandbytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
                    commandaddress = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)(commandbytes.Length), AllocationType.Commit | AllocationType.Reserve, MemoryProtection.ExecuteReadWrite);
                    int bytesWritten = 0;
                    int bytesWritten2 = commandbytes.Length;
                    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, commandaddress, commandbytes, commandbytes.Length, out bytesWritten2);

                    Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(commandaddress.ToInt64()), 0, cbuf_addtext_wrapper, 9, 4);
                    Array.Copy(callbytes, 0, cbuf_addtext_wrapper, 16, 4);

                    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, cbuf_addtext_alloc, cbuf_addtext_wrapper, cbuf_addtext_wrapper.Length, out bytesWritten);

                    IntPtr bytesOut;
                    CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, 0, cbuf_addtext_alloc, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out bytesOut);

                    if(cbuf_addtext_alloc != IntPtr.Zero && commandaddress != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, cbuf_addtext_alloc, cbuf_addtext_wrapper.Length, FreeType.Release);
                        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, commandaddress, cbuf_addtext_wrapper.Length, FreeType.Release);
                    }
                }
                cbuf_addtext_alloc = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
```

im really stuff so i would appreciate if someone can help 
me with this issue its probably something small anyways please reply sooon!

thank you.

Comment: Are you getting errors or exceptions?

Comment: Obviously the command that is sent is the only difference - what is the value of each command?  Have you traced through it in the debugger to see where the problem occurs?

Comment: no im not getting any errors button1_Click works button2_Click doesnt

Comment: It'd be infinitely easier to help you if you could take a little of your own time to debug your code as we can't. We don't know what value is getting sent from these textboxes, or what errors/exceptions you're getting. That said, I would change `command == ""` to `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command)`

Comment: Why do you have textBox1 and richTextBox1? Do you want to have those different objects? Or just one of them?

Comment: one of them can only have one line of text and the other (richtextbox) can have more then 1 line

Comment: Did you actually wire the up the  click event or did you just copy and change `1` to `2`?

Comment: I fixed it lol i was so stupid i didnt wire the click event up thanks tycobb

Comment: This question should be deleted, will not help anyone!

Answer (score 1):

Like  this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox1.Text))
   {
      Send(richTextBox1.Text);
   }
   else if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))     
   {    
      Send(textBox1.Text);
   } 
   else
   {
       return;  
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you wire up the `Click` event in order for your code to fire. This gets set for you automatically in the designer code (auto-generated) when you double click the button. But you can also auto generate the method and subscription when looking at the list of events.

Copying an event function or coding it by hand will not automatically do it. However, with the code already in place, you should be able to now select it from the Click event drop down when in the designer.